# Jon Eskdale's Touchscreen dimmer

Tags: pi-3

I have the official 7" touchscreen installed on a Pi 3B running Strech V9.

I have installed the touchscreen-dimmer project from the Github repository & followed the readme.me

the screen dims OK when I run

`sudo ./timeout 10 15 event0`

I have copied timeout & run-dimmer.sh to /etc/ & added:
/etc/run-dimmer.sh to /etc/rc.local

I have run the command:

```
sudo su -c 'echo SUBSYSTEM==\"backlight\", RUN+=\"/bin/chmod 0666 /sys/class/backlight/%k/brightness /sys/class/backlight/%k/bl_power\" > /etc/udev/rules.d/99-backlight.rules'
```

I got no feedback or error when I ran this command? Is this right?

I have ls installed & working.

I am using the default time & levels in run-dimmer.sh.

The upshot is that the screen does not dim after 30 secs.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try my version https://github.com/DougieLawson/backlight_dimmer

Comment: *"I got no feedback or error when I ran this command?*" That command just writes a udev configuration file.  You might have to run `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules` or reboot to make it effective.

Comment: I tried Doug's file as is & got the same result - ie no dimming.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the file permissions on /etc/timeout & /etc/run-dimmer.sh so that they have -rwxrwsrwx 1 root root 1151. (/etc/run_dimmer.sh is coloured orange).

File permissions for /etc/timeout are:
-rwxrwsrwx 1 root root 12684

I can run /etc/./run-dimmer.sh in a terminal window & it executes & the screen dims after 30 secs.

However, when I add /etc/./run-dimmer.sh
or
cd /etc
./run-dimmer.sh

to /etc/rc.local it doesn't work.

I'm not sure what to do to run run-dimmer.sh from rc.local

I tried Doug Lawson's app and followed his readme.md but it still won't execute from within rc.local

I have now got this fully working using Doug's app but I had to modify Doug's script to explicitly point to event0, rather than using the $dev variable to wake up the screen on touch. I am running the script from etc/profile, not rc.local. I also found an issue. If the pi is rebooted with the screen blanked it does not come back to full brightness. I fixed this by writing a script that runs the command echo 120 > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/brightness. I also put this script into /etc/profile and ran it before the display dimmer.

Comment: Got Doug's version to work by running it from /etc/profiles as run-timeout.sh &. I had to replace $dev in the nice command line  with event0 to re-enable the screen on touch.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.